# New Worldpay API with Cartthrob

Tags: cartthrob, worldpay

We're setting up a new website that uses Cartthrob (v2.70 currently installed) and need to use Worldpay as the payment gateway.

Selecting 'RBS Worldpay Redirect Payment Gateway' and testing seems to hook us into what looks like a legacy part of Worldpay. I believe they have a new API that looks and works in a much nicer way.

Do newer versions of Cartthrob have the newer payment gateway? Can we get around this by upgrading?

Or, do we have write our own payment gateway for this?

Any advice gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

(I'm with Vector; we make CartThrob)

The newer CTs use the same Worldpay API as 2.7, so upgrading wouldn't change that. You'd have to write your own, or consider contacting us (support@cartthrob.com) if you'd like us to do it!

Comment: Ok, thanks Matt. Will look into this further and let you know if we need your assistance.

Comment: I'd also be very interested in this (with WorldPay's new json api). Have there been any developments on this? Using CT 2.71.

Comment: @SyA nothing has changed on that front unfortunately. Feel free to contact support@cartthrob.com if you'd like to discuss us working on it for you!